# VSCode: CMD clicking css file location brings up different file path and suggests create a file

Tags: html, css, node.js, visual-studio-code, handlebars.js

A picture is worth a thousand words so here it is;

[Picture, I am confuesed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmAM1.png)

I do not know why it does not link up with my css file I have created, it is exact file path!

Can anyone please help me, I want to style my handlebars and I cannot!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

anything that starts with `./` is a **relative** path. It's relative to the current file path. As the error suggests, it is therefore looking for a *styles* folder inside *views/layouts*.

Use either

```
styles/styles.css
```

or

```
../../styles/styles.css
```